# What is all this stuff in the CKEditor folder?

Tags: directory, ckeditor

A while ago I downloaded the latest version (3.1) of the CKEditor text editor.

The directory name was `ckeditor` and I deleted the `ckeditor/_source` and `ckeditor/_samples` sub-directories, then I referenced the `ckeditor.js` file in my html pages, like so :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

This works well. To make config changes, I have been modifying the `ckeditor/config.js` file.

However, as of late, I have been reading various web resources that say 'do not delete the _source' folder and other such ominous messages.

**What is this `_source` folder?**
 
**What is all the stuff at the root of the ckeditor folder?** and,
**What is safe to remove from the folder?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The _source folder are all the uncompressed scripts, and should be used just to read, learn and modify the code (that you must compress afterwards). It shouldn't be available in a production server.

The *.HTML files are docs for you to read

The *.php and *.asp are server integration that you don't need in the way that you are using

The *_source.js and ckeditor.pack are used to work with the _source folder and then generate the compressed version

The adapters folder includes other integration (currently jQuery)

Answer (score 4):

I was wondering the same thing. I think it's explained pretty well on this page:

http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Minimum_Setup